# (Ubuntu) Non-root user has root access, but isn't in the sudo group

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, users, root

A user on my AWS EC2 instance has unrestricted sudo access, and no password prompt.  This is an Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS VM.

Here's an example of the problem:

```
~$ whoami
ubuntu
~$ groups
ubuntu
~$ sudo deluser ubuntu sudo
/usr/sbin/deluser: The user `ubuntu' is not a member of group `sudo'.
~$ sudo whoami
root
```

As you can see, I've already removed this user from all groups but their own (`ubuntu`).

Here is my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
# Defaults       secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL


# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
#%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I commented out the `%admin` group entry and also the `secure_path` entry in the `Defaults` just to test.

I've rebooted the machine and logged back in as `ubuntu`. I still have sudo access and can switch to the root user unrestricted.

```
$ sudo su
root@ip-x-x-x-x:/home/ubuntu#
```

The root user **does** have a password on the account.

I have added a new user, and confirmed that this new user had to be added to the group `sudo` before being able to use sudo.

So, why does my user `ubuntu` have free root access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you see this line near/at the end of your `/etc/sudoers` file?

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

This loads files that are present in the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory, treating them as part of the `/etc/sudoers` file.  As the comment line above that line indicates, the man page for the sudoers file explains the full details of how the `#includedir` directive works.

Have a look at the files in the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory and you'll find the entry that gives the `ubuntu` user permission to invoke commands as `root`.

Comment: Doh! I thought the # indicated the line was commented out. After checking the `sudoers.d/` directory, I see a cloud init file, and inside that, I see the rule. Thanks!!

Rule: 
`ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

Comment: @David00 yes, for some reason that directive doesn't treat the `#` character as a comment.  Perhaps it was to avoid failures with older versions of sudo that didn't support `#includedir`.  Those versions would think it's merely a comment and not error out while reading the file, leaving a non-secure configuration.  (just a guess)